# Is there a way to execute all possible orders of statements?

Tags: python

I have a programme looking for the shortest path in a grid from one position to the other.

I think the shortest path returned will depend on which direction in the array the function calls first.

Is there a way to have the same function run the below, except once for each possible order of North, South, East, West?

I understand that I could have 4! similar functions, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Apologies in advance for ignorance on my part, I'm not particularly experienced!

```
def find_path(world, path, robotx, roboty, goalx, goaly, size):
print("Robot at: ", robotx, ",", roboty)
#print(path)
time.sleep(0.7)
if [robotx, roboty] == [goalx, goaly]:
    path_count = 0
    print("Woohoo! Goal found at ", goalx, ',', goaly, '. ', "Steps taken: ", path_count)
    print(path)
    return path
else:
    #South
    if robotx != size and world[robotx + 1][roboty] in (0, 2):
        world[robotx + 1][roboty] = 3
        path.add_head(Node([robotx + 1, roboty]))
        find_path(world, path, robotx + 1, roboty, goalx, goaly, size)

    #East
    if roboty != size and world[robotx][roboty + 1] in (0, 2):
        world[robotx][roboty + 1] = 3
        path.add_head(Node([robotx, roboty + 1]))
        find_path(world, path, robotx, roboty + 1, goalx, goaly, size)

    #North
    if robotx != 0 and world[robotx - 1][roboty] in (0, 2):
        world[robotx - 1][roboty] = 3
        path.add_head(Node([robotx - 1, roboty]))
        find_path(world, path, robotx - 1, roboty, goalx, goaly, size)

    #West
    if roboty != 0 and world[robotx][roboty - 1] in (0, 2):
        world[robotx][roboty - 1] = 3
        path.add_head(Node([robotx, roboty - 1]))
        find_path(world, path, robotx, roboty - 1, goalx, goaly, size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Python is a bit rusty, so someone else might be better at giving you the exact syntax, but in principle, you need to create a function that looks like this:

```
def checkDir( chkX, chkY):
    ...
return
```

then replace those -1 and +1 values with chkX, chkY as appropriate.

Then you just call the function 4 times that looks like this:

```
checkDir( 1, 1)
checkDir( -1, 1)
checkDir( 1, -1)
checkDir( -1, -1)
```

Comment: I think it should be `checkDir(1,0)`, `checkDir(-1,0)`, `checkDir(0,1)` and `checkDir(0,-1)`. Also, to find and choose from all permutations consider `list(itertools.permutation([(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]))`.